# How to hide and show the payment method based on shipping address country to sort the payment method

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, magento2.3.3

This code has worked to hide and show the payment method based on the shipping address country.

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //shipping company field
        $shippingCompanyField = $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();

```
    $paymentMethod = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

    if ($shippingCompanyField == 'IN') {
        if ($paymentMethod == "multisafepay_giropay") {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
        }
    }else{
        if ($paymentMethod == "multisafepay_giropay") {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);
        }
    }
    
}
```

If the customer address chooses a different country based on that it will hide and show, Initially "multisafepay_giropay" has second position after hiding then show the same payment gateway it will show on the last position in "multisafepay_giropay", we need to show the same position, not the last position.
how to maintain the position(sort_order) in Magento 2.3?
Admin configuration payment gateway sort order is not working in this scenario.